# Subversion update always hangs on specific image file

Tags: svn

Someone on our team committed a file successfully.  Now when the rest of us try to update and grab that file, Versions hangs on that specific file forever (it doesn't even timeout).  Is the file corrupted?  How do I go about fixing this?

Update: Another team member just tried to update and his is hanging as well, but on a different file.

Comment: Have you updated your clients? Can anyone update? Have you tried explicitly on just the file?

Comment: I tried updating again and it finally showed an error, but I'm sorry I didn't write it down.  After that I just deleted it and committed that and then everyone was able to update.